# Can't return a void result

Tags: java

```
private String udaReference(List<Uda> udas, String uda_code) {
        /*
         * return udas.stream().filter(a ->
         * a.getCode().equals(uda_code)).findFirst().get().getReferences().get(0)
         * .getCode();
         */
         
         return udas.stream().filter(a -> a.getCode().equals(uda_code)).findFirst().ifPresent(att->{
                att.getReferences().get(0).getCode();
            });
    }
```

I get error in return statement saying can't return a void statement.

how to resolve above statement

Comment: Why do you *want* to "return a void statement"?

Comment: `ifPresent` does not have any return value. What do you want to do?

Comment: How to return String getCode by fixing above return statement

Comment: Please share an [mcve]

Comment: I guess, the comment code whould give you the correct answer

Comment: BTW: Take care of java naming conventions. Names should be camelCase not snake_case

Comment: @Jens It's sonar issue that is asking to use Optional Method in place of get..return udas.stream().filter(a ->a.getCode().equals(uda_code)).findFirst().orElse(null).getReferences().get(0).getCode();  Would this be good?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I would favor `orElseThrow()` over orElse(null).

Comment: @VGR: I don't disagree, but that opens up another large discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You cant return void (lowercase) just becouse a void function means that this function has no return value, simple do something.

If you want to return something you have to use a function that return you something.

In your case I think you want to return the first code of references of the first `Uda` with `uda_code` in your list.

Here's the solution

```
private String udaReference(List<Uda> udas, String uda_code) {
    return udas.stream().filter(a -> a.getCode().equals(uda_code))
            .findFirst()
            .map(a -> a.getReferences().get(0).getCode()) // if findFirst() return a value, get the value you want to return
            .orElse(null); // if findFirst() do not return a value, return null
}
```

pls notice that this solution works if and only if you are sure that `references` is always not null and  has always at least 1 value, else it throws a NullPointerException.

Or else you have to use this solution:

```
public String udaReferenceSafe(List<Uda> udas, String uda_code) {
    return udas.stream().filter(a -> a.getCode().equals(uda_code))
            .findFirst()
            .filter(a -> a.getReferences() != null)
            .flatMap(a -> a.getReferences().stream().findFirst())
            .map(Uda::getCode)
            .orElse(null);
}
```